# Single-mode hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, oscillators

I´m  a bit stuck with an exercise I have to do for a class of mine.
We have been given a Hamiltonian

$$\hat{H}=\hbar\omega\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}+\hbar\theta\left(\hat{a}^2+\hat{a}^{\dagger 2}\right)$$

and were asked to calculate the time evolution of $\hat{x}(t)$ and $\hat{p}(t)$. I tried to first calculate the time evolution of the ladder operators of which they consist using Heisenberg's equations of motion $$\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{H},\hat{a}]=\frac{d}{dt}\hat{a}(t).$$ I then receive two coupled differential equations:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{a}(t)=-i(\omega\hat{a}+2\theta\hat{a}^{\dagger})$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t)=i(\omega\hat{a}^{\dagger}+2\theta\hat{a}). $$

However, I don't really know how to solve these kind of equations. I would be very grateful for any of your help,

Comment: This is a standard first order ODE with constant coefficients ($\dot{y} = C y$). I'm sure you have seen it before.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of normal modes? You can write your system of differential equations in matrix form and then diagonalize it...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am not too familiar with this way of solving coupled differential equations but had already found a page about normal modes at the time I posted this. The problem is that the matrix that connects the time derivatives of the ladder operators and the operators themselves isn't a normal matrix so it cannot be diagonalized. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The matrix you have written in your coupled differential equations is indeed normal and can be diagonalized. Hint, the eigenvalues are $\pm\sqrt{\omega^2 - 4\theta^2}$

Comment: Thank you for the help! Before starting to diagonalize the matrix I checked if it commuted with its transposed conjugate to make sure I could solve the equation trough finding the normal modes. I probably just messed up there. Thanks again I will try to flag this as solved

Answer (score 1):

Although this might be a bit hifalutin, there is an algebraic structure to this problem since the operators
$$
K_0=\frac{1}{2}(\hat a^\dagger a+\hat a\hat a^\dagger)\, ,\qquad 
K_+=\hat a^\dagger\hat a^\dagger\, ,\qquad
K_-=\hat a\hat a
$$
close on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$. One can verify that $\{K_0,K_\pm\}$ actually close under commutation, and the commutation relations differ from those of angular momentum by an single sign.  You can find details on $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ in

1. Ban, Masashi. "Decomposition formulas for su (1, 1) and su (2) Lie algebras and their applications in quantum optics." JOSA B 10.8 (1993): 1347-1359.
2. Wodkiewicz, K., and J. H. Eberly. "Coherent states, squeezed fluctuations, and the SU (2) am SU (1, 1) groups in quantum-optics applications." JOSA B 2.3 (1985): 458-466.

   both of which emphasize the similarities and differences with angular momentum theory.  There is also useful material in
3. Ui, Haruo. "su (1, 1) quasi-spin formalism of the many-boson system in a spherical field." Annals of Physics 49.1 (1968): 69-92.

Thus your Hamiltonian can be rewritten as
$$
H= \alpha K_0+\beta K_x
$$
where $K_x=\frac{1}{2}(K_++K_-)$.  A transformation $T(\tau)$ generated by
$K_y=\frac{1}{2i}(K_+-K_-)$:
$$
T(\tau)=e^{-i \tau K_y}
$$
with suitable $\tau$ will bring your Hamiltonian to diagonal form.

In the literature, $T(\tau)$ is often referred to as a squeezing transformation, or Bogoliubov transformation.  Its effect is to transform $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$ into linear combinations $\hat b$ and $\hat b^\dagger$ such that
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} 
\hat b \\ \hat b^\dagger\end{array}
\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cosh\frac{1}{2}\tau&\sinh\frac{1}{2}\tau\\
\sinh\frac{1}{2}\tau&\cosh\frac{1}{2}\tau\\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} 
\hat a \\ \hat a^\dagger\end{array}
\right)\, .
$$  In terms of the position and momentum, the transformation scales $x\to X= \zeta x$ and $p\to p/\zeta$, which is equivalent to changing the frequency of the oscillator.  The actual calculation would be in the spirit of diagonalizing $H=\alpha L_z+\beta L_x$ using a rotation generated by $L_y$.